# Access: search for more than one parameter?

Tags: ms-access, parameter, dbms

I need to perform several queries, looking for more than one parameter.

for example: in my field "lenght" I want to extract values matching both 4.6 and 4.7.
then, next time I need 5.8 and 5.9, and so on. I will be searching for more parameters.

Is it possible to create an input form where i can input something like:

```
4.6 AND 4.7
```

PS: would it be better to use a different database software?

Answer (score 1):

If you'll input "4.6, 4.7", it could construct sql-query, using [IN predicate](http://www.sql-tutorial.ru/en/book_predicate_in.html) that will give you something like:

```
where length IN(4.6, 4.7)
```